# What is the convention for considering a function with side-effects in Racket/Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, convention

Obviously, it is a convention in Racket/Scheme to append an exclamation point to function names that perform mutation. For example, in Racket, `set!`, `box-set!`, `vector-set!`, etc. Certain functions have side-effects, like `print`, but since those side-effects are "harmless," I understand why they don't usually come with exclamation marks attached.

However, this convention is arbitrarily violated. For example, [`async-channel-get`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/async-channel.html?q=recv#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fasync-channel..rkt%29._async-channel-get%29%29) and [`async-channel-put`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/async-channel.html?q=recv#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fasync-channel..rkt%29._async-channel-put%29%29) clearly perform mutation, but they don't have the "mutation marker" appended to their names. This can be somewhat justified by pointing out that these are channels, clearly mutation-based, so the "!" would be superfluous.

This is not a valid justification for everything, though. Racket's [WebSockets library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/websocket.html) provides [`ws-send!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/websocket.html#%28def._%28%28lib._net%2Fwebsocket%2Fconn..rkt%29._ws-send%21%29%29) and [`ws-close!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/websocket.html#%28def._%28%28lib._net%2Fwebsocket%2Fconn..rkt%29._ws-close%21%29%29) functions, both with the obvious markers, but [`ws-recv`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/websocket.html#%28def._%28%28lib._net%2Fwebsocket%2Fconn..rkt%29._ws-recv%29%29) does *not!* Is this just an isolated violation of the convention, or is there some rule?

I ask this mostly to be sure of how I should name functions in my own code. When should I use the exclamation mark, when should I not? I recognize that it's just a convention, not a rule, and it will likely be somewhat inconsistent, but I still would like to know what the best practices are.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think #!racket has its own naming convention, but according to [this R5RS page](http://www.scheme.com/tspl2d/intro.html) you can read:

> The names of procedures and syntactic forms that cause side effects
>   end with an exclamation point ( ! ). These include set! and
>   vector-set!. Procedures that perform input or output technically cause
>   side effects, but their names are exceptions to this rule.

In the [Scheme wiki variable naming convention](http://community.schemewiki.org/?variable-naming-convention) it says `procedure!` is for "significant side effects". IMO that means the side effects is the hero of the procedure as in `set-car!` and `set!` while `read` returns a value which perhaps is the main feature of read?